# `ltluatex.tex` vs. `luatexbase.sty`

Tags: luatex

Both `ltluatex.tex` (from the LaTeX kernel) and `luatexbase.sty` (as an add-on package) share the same Lua namespace, namely `luatexbase`; they also share functions with the same name.  However, these functions are not compatible – in particular, `luatexbase.add_to_callback` differs.

What is the recommended, future-proof way to find out whether the stuff from `ltluatex.tex` is used?  Or to say it differently, I want to reject `luatexbase.sty`.

Comment: luatexbase simply `\input{ltluatex}%` if it is not being used with latex, when `ltluatex` is always loaded

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with any latex package you can prevent it loading via

```
\@namedef{ver@luatexbase.sty}{}
```

so latex thinks it is already loaded.

But there should be no need

The current `luatexbase.sty` was written at the same time as `ltluatex`, by the same people, it is intended as a compatible extension, replacing the original `luatexbase.sty` that pre-dates `ltluatex`.

The extended `luatexbase.add_to_callback` has an extra optional `priority` argument but if it is not used, the behaviour is as in `ltluatex` and either way the actual registering of the callback is done via the `ltluatex` version (saved as `luatexbase.base_add_to_callback`). The extended version just re-orders the callback list if `priority` is used. All the internal tables recording the callbacks are the ones defined by `ltluatex`.